# SQL - SUM Values based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble loading this table. I want all Quantity values <500 summed where the NameCode is the same. If the sum is still less than 500, don't insert.  Is this possible?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GovQuantity](
        [NameCode] [varchar](40) NULL,
        [Quantity] [decimal](18,6) NULL,
        )



    INSERT INTO GovQuantity
    SELECT  d.NumNameCode
        , Quantity = CASE WHEN QUANTITY < 500 THEN SUM(Quantity) ELSE Quantity END 
          FROM [...]              
    GROUP BY NumNameCode, Quantity
```

Currently have this:

```
 NameCode     Quantity
 ArmyGuard       125
 ArmyGuard       605
 ArmyGuard       65
 Boeing          420
 Boeing          750
 Boeing          100
```

Need:

```
NameCode     Quantity
 ArmyGuard       605
 Boeing          520
 Boeing          750
```

Comment: That is extremely odd. You want aggregate and non-aggregate data at the same time? And where did the other 190 for ArmyGuard go?

Comment: This makes no sense. If you want to sum all quantity values < 500, then how does (ArmyGuard, 605) appear in your output? That appears to be exactly opposite of what you wrote.

Comment: What if you have a namecode with two values over 500?

Comment: Yeah I think my logic is wrong.

Comment: At the very least, I think you need to move the aggregate function outside of the case statement. Something like `SUM (case when quantity < 500 then quantity else 0 end)`.

Comment: Let us know the logic for `Boeing` has 2 rows... whereas `ArmyGuard` has only one row..?

Comment: So tell us what the correct logic is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest way to write this is with `union all`:

```
select NameCode, sum(Quantity) as Quantity
from govquantity
where Quantity < 500
group by NameCode
having sum(Quantity) >= 500
union all
select NameCode, Quantity
from govquantity
where Quantity >= 500;
```

It is tempting to write this using a single aggregation:

I think you simply want:

```
SELECT d.NumNameCode, SUM(Quantity)
FROM [...]     
WHERE QUANTITY < 500         
GROUP BY NumNameCode,
         (CASE WHEN Quantity >= 500 THEN Quantity END)
HAVING SUM(QUANTITY) >= 500;
```

However, this will mess up if two `quantity` values are the same and greater than 500.

If you had a unique id (or at least unique per name), then this would be:

```
SELECT d.NumNameCode, SUM(Quantity)
FROM [...]     
WHERE QUANTITY < 500         
GROUP BY NumNameCode,
         (CASE WHEN Quantity >= 500 THEN Id END)
HAVING SUM(QUANTITY) >= 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this.

This will display individual rows >= 500 and aggregate the misc. others.

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select NameCode
      ,Quantity
      ,RN       = Row_Number() over (Partition By NameCode Order by Quantity)
 From  [dbo].[GovQuantity]
)
Select NameCode
      ,Quantity = sum(Quantity)
 From  cte
 Group By NameCode,case when Quantity >=500 then RN else 0 end
 Having sum(Quantity) > 500
 Order by NameCode
```

**Returns**

```
NameCode    Quantity
ArmyGuard   605
Boeing      520
Boeing      750
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (NameCode  VARCHAR(10), Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES

('ArmyGuard', 125),
('ArmyGuard', 605),
('ArmyGuard', 65 ),
('Boeing   ', 420),
('Boeing   ', 750),
('Boeing   ', 100)


SELECT NameCode, SUM(Quantity) Quantity FROM @T
GROUP BY
    NameCode, 
    (CASE WHEN Quantity < 500 THEN 0 ELSE Quantity END)
HAVING 
    SUM(Quantity) >= 500
ORDER BY 
    NameCode
```

Result:

```
NameCode   Quantity
---------- -----------
ArmyGuard  605
Boeing     520
Boeing     750
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `union all` :

```
select NumNameCode, sum(Quantity) as Quantity
from table t
where Quantity < 500
group by NumNameCode
union all
select NumNameCode, Quantity
from table t
where Quantity >= 500;
```